# Change hyperlink style when converting DOCX to PDF using docx4j

Tags: pdf, docx, docx4j

I'm trying to change hyperlink style in Table of Content when converting DOCX to PDF using docx4j (export-FO). Currently in the docx file ToC items are plain black text, but in the output PDF file they are blue and underscored. How can I make them stay with the initial style?

[DOCX](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=test-doc.docx)

[PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=test-doc-2.pdf)

Comment: Which converter are you using, export-FO (on your classpath), or the default conversion service?

Comment: I use default converter service

Comment: I was wrong - I'm using export-FO.